# MongoDB replica set not picking a PRIMARY with 4 of 6 members UP

Tags: high-availability, mongodb

I have 6 instances running on Scaleway , 3 on ARM servers and 3 on Virtual Ubuntu Servers .

```
mongodb1 ARM (mongodb 3.4.9)
mongodb2 ARM (mongodb 3.4.9)
mongodb3 ARM (mongodb 3.4.9)
mongodb4 VPS (mongodb 3.4.15)
mongodb5 VPS (mongodb 3.4.15)
mongodb6 VPS (mongodb 3.4.15)
```

These 6 instances are running mongodb and are joined in a replica set.

More often than not , the ARM instances turn off or Hard reboot for unknown  or implicit reasons .

When i connect to mongodb on the up and running distances , i see that they are all SECONDARY and none of them are elected private. Shouldn't it be such so that the system can go on ?

I also get one more instance up and running , bringing the situation to 4 of 6 members UP , still no change.

After I start the 5th member of the replica set , bringing the situation to 5 of 6 members UP , finally a node is selected PRIMARY

here is the output of rs.status() :

```
"members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "mongodb1:27017",
                    "health" : 0,
                    "state" : 8,
                    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                    "uptime" : 0,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:29:56.945Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:39.905Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Connection refused",
                    "configVersion" : -1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "mongodb2:27017",
                    "health" : 0,
                    "state" : 8,
                    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                    "uptime" : 0,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:29:56.944Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:39.912Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Connection refused",
                    "configVersion" : -1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "mongodb3:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 966,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1533975634, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(14)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1533975634, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(14)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:34Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:34Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:30:00.654Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:29:59.814Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
                    "configVersion" : 6
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "name" : "mongodb4:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 1814348,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1533975634, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(14)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1533975634, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(14)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:34Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:34Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:29:58.088Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:30:00.186Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
                    "configVersion" : 6
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 4,
                    "name" : "mongodb5:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 4316484,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1533975634, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(14)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:34Z"),
                    "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
                    "configVersion" : 6,
                    "self" : true
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 5,
                    "name" : "mongodb6:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 1639135,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1533975634, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(14)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1533975634, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(14)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:34Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-08-11T08:20:34Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:29:59.990Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-08-14T07:29:56.473Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
                    "configVersion" : 6
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
```

Comment: With 6 voting members in your replica set you need 4 healthy voting members in order to elect or maintain a primary. In your current `rs.status()` output the first two members are unreachable and one of your secondaries (`_id:4`) cannot find a member to sync from. If you review your `mongod` log files there should be more information on the election process and health of members (try search for log lines including `REPL`). Are you running the same version of MongoDB on all members? If not, what version(s) are you using? Are all of your servers 64-bit?

Comment: I didn't notice the "mongodb5" saying "cannot find a member to sync from" . That must have been the case . First Three members are 3.4.9 , and the last 3 members are 3.4.15